# Is Google Forms quiz result adjustable

Tags: google-forms

Does everyone see everyone's result when sent after a Google Forms quiz or just their own points (is this adjustable)?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: I'm sorry serenesat, but I don't like your modification. It is not about changing the result but about how to SHOW the result. Your questioning can mislead internauts (again) and leave them looking for an adequate answer, more so, ask a new question on the forum, don't you think? Sorry for my reaction and stay sane, Rache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an adjustable option called **See summary charts and text responses**, which is turned **off** by default:

[image: See summary charts and text responses]

Answer (score 1):

It is given as an option *("adjustable")*
But.

### Be very careful

Once you select `See summary charts and responses` **every single submitter can see ALL of them** after submitting the form.

[image]

Not only this, but **anyone with the link can see them as well** *(using a simple copy/paste to an email)*.

[image]